# read from csv and how to update images like base image ,small_image, thumbnail through REST api in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am unable to update the images through rest api in magento 2,below this is my code.please guide me right direction.Here got the error

```
string(47) "{"message":"Request does not match any route."}"


$adminUrl = 'http://localhost/#####/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token/';
        $ch = curl_init();
        $data = array("username" => "######", "password" => "############");

        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
        $token = curl_exec($ch);
        $token=  json_decode($token);

        //Use above token into header
        $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token","Content-Type: application/json");


        foreach ($list as $sku => $skus) {


          $requestUrl='http://localhost/##############/index.php/rest/V1/products/' . $skus['Product ID'] . '/media';


//print_r($requestUrl);exit;

        $productData = array();

$productData = [
        "custom_attributes" => [
                ["attribute_code" => "image", "value" => "/w/i/sample_1.jpg"],
                ["attribute_code" => "small_image", "value" => "/w/i/sample_2.jpg"],
                ["attribute_code" => "thumbnail", "value" => "/w/i/sample_2.jpg"]

            ]
    ];


//print_r($productData);exit;






        $productData = json_encode(array('product' => $productData));

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          $response = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          var_dump($response);

          unset($productData);
          unset($sampleProductData);
        }
```